# Не работает request из формы

Tags: php, laravel

При нажатии `submit` страница перезагружается и больше ничего не происходит
Пытаюсь вывести что пришло в `request через dd()` и просто ничего не происходит

```
Route::post('/additem/submit', \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class)->name('productadd');
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'price' => 'required',
            'data' => 'required|string',
            'category' => 'required|string',
            'game' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'description.required'=>'Description Is Required',
            'price.required'=>'Price Is Required',
        ];
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(ProductRequest $request) {
        $data = $request->validated();

        dd($data);

        return compact($data);
    }
}
```

```
<form id="additemForm" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('productadd') }}">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="aditem row ">
                        <div class="d-flex col ara">
                            <div class="select-game mr-1">
                                <button class="hhs2">Выберите игру</button>
                                <div id="game" class="selef border">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <div class="box border align-items-center d-flex">
                                                    <!--<div class="selected"></div> !-->
                                                </div>
                                                <span>SA:MP</span>
                                            </a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <div class="box border"></div>
                                                <span>CR:MP</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <div class="box border"></div>
                                                <span>SA:MP Mobile</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <div class="box border"></div>
                                                <span>MTA</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="select-game hg">
                                <button class="hhs1">Выберите категорию</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <div class="col descsell">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Описание товара</label>
                                <textarea type="text" name="description" class="form-control fo-14 noout" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4" placeholder="Введите полное описание товара"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="col get-item">
                                <label for="getitem" class="form-label">Данные товара</label>
                                <textarea type="text" name="data" class="form-control fo-14 noout" id="getitem" rows="3" placeholder="Введите данные которые получит покупатель после оплаты"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center cen">
                                <span>Цена:</span>
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm w-25 pl-2">
                                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price1" placeholder="0 ₽" aria-label="0RUB">
                                </div>
                                <div class="adbtn">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-goods">
                                        <span>Добавить товар</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений": приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.
Обратите внимание на мою правку на будущее.

Answer (score 0):

Приложение падает на валидации реквеста и даже не доходит до dd(). Попробуй убрать все правила в rules и проверь еще раз.
*Если быть точнее, то у тебя не приходит параметр "game", который является 'required'.*

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).